# Stripe: No such price: '{{PRICE_ID}}'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

Trying to integrate stripe and test out checkout. When making the post request, I get back the following two errors:
Cart.jsx?a2f4:19          POST http://localhost:3000/api/stripe 400 (Bad Request)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'N', "No such price: '{{PRICE_ID}}'"... is not valid JSON

Here is the relevant code from my cart.jsx component, api/stripe.js, and getStripe.js

Have spent tons of time trying to figure this out but I feel like I'm just blind and missing something obvious. Help will be greatly appreciated!!

Cart.jsx

```
const Cart = () => {
  const cartRef = useRef();
  const { totalPrice, totalQuantities, cartItems, setShowCart, toggleCartItemQuantity, onRemove } = useStateContext();

  const handleCheckout = async () => {
    const stripe = await getStripe();
    const response = await fetch('/api/stripe', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(cartItems),
    });
    console.log(response)
    if(response.statusCode === 500) return;
    
    const data = await response.json();

    toast.loading('Redirecting...');

    stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: data.id });
  }
```

stripe.js

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
//const stripe = require(`${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`)
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    console.log(req.body.cartItems)
    try {
      const params = {
        submit_type: 'pay',
        mode: 'payment',
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        billing_address_collection: 'auto',
        shipping_options: [
          { shipping_rate: 'shr_1MmbQsDxppDAFTDHT3PKZP9Q'},
          { shipping_rate: 'shr_1MmbSBDxppDAFTDHAnfijv4n'},
        ],
        line_items: [
          {
            // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
            price: '{{PRICE_ID}}',
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      }

      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(params);
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

getStripe.js

````
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

let stripePromise;

const getStripe = () => {
    if(!stripePromise) {
        //stripePromise = loadStripe(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}`)
        stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
    }

    return stripePromise;
}

export default getStripe;```




the console.log just under the handler function in stripe.js should be returning json detailing the item that is being checked out when clicking 'Pay With Stripe' but instead returns the first mentioned error.
````

Comment: Where is PRICE_ID coming from? The req? If yes please add what you see in the log for cartitems in stripe.js.

Comment: Console.log(cartItems) returns the followg: 0
: 
details
: 
"A second pair of headphones"
image
: 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
name
: 
"Headphones"
price
: 
49
quantity
: 
1
slug
: 
{_type: 'slug', current: 'headphones_new'}
_createdAt
: 
"2023-03-16T11:43:48Z"
_id
: 
"d0dda876-a4c9-4939-aa60-17904cb7551e"
_rev
: 
"AJtk7DlWUshxy8sgPfwUFB"
_type
: 
"product"
_updatedAt
: 
"2023-03-16T11:43:48Z"

Comment: another detail worth mentioning is that the console.log(req.body.cartItems) is returning undefined in the console before even getting to the {{PRICE_ID}} line

Comment: well...for whatever reason it appears that passing JSON.stringify(cartItems) simply makes cartItems the body, so req.body.cartItems returned nothing. Changing it to JSON.stringify({cartItems: cartItems}) now allows me to access it. Not sure if something was changed with JSON.stringify but I've seen the initial syntax work for others.

Comment: Which line does the error exactly throw from in `stripe.js`? "No such price: '{{PRICE_ID}}" indicated that the price ID was invalid. `PRICE_ID` should be replaced by an actual price ID that is in `price_xxx` format.

Answer (score 0):

well...for whatever reason it appears that passing

```js
JSON.stringify(cartItems)
```

simply makes cartItems the body, so `req.body.cartItems` returned nothing. Changing it to:

```js
JSON.stringify({cartItems: cartItems})
```

now allows me to access it. Not sure if something was changed with `JSON.stringify` but I've seen the initial syntax work for others.